# How to setText from a DialogFragment with DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, textview, android-dialogfragment

I'm building an app where you can choose a date with a DatePickerDialog, after you select and tap in "Ok", the date you choose must be shown in a TextView.

I'm having problems doing that since i can't just use "setText.mTexView(foo)" inside a DialogFragment... I've tried passing the textview through the constructor or getting the tv in the fragment but i couldn't, help please.

This is my code:

```
public class PickDate_main extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText tv_fecha;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pickdate_main);
}


public void showDatePickerDialog(View v){//This method is executed from the layout with a button

    PickDate_Dialog dialog = new PickDate_Dialog();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    dialog.show(ft, "Date pickeerr");
}
}
```

--

```
public class PickDate_Dialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

public PickDate_Dialog(){
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new PickDate_Dialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {


    String date = day + "-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;

    //I want to write the string "data", i suppose it must be here
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should work if you send the textview to PickDate_Dialog, save it, and call it when necessary. Not sure about `return new PickDate_Dialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);` though.

```
public class PickDate_Dialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    private EditText dateEditText;

    public PickDate_Dialog(EditText et){
        dateEditText = et;
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //Do you have a constructor for this? This is likely your issue

        return new PickDate_Dialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {


        String date = day + "-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
        if (dateEditText != null)
            dateEditText.setText(date);
    }

}
```

However, here are a few more ideas:

Option 1: Have a look at interfaces. It's a way to allow you to send callbacks between classes (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener is an example). Create a new interface in your Dialog class

```
public interface PickDateInterface {
    void onDateSet(String date)
}
```

create a variable for it

private PickDateInterface mPDInterface;

and add it to the original onDateSet

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    String date = day + "-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;

    if (mPDInterface != null) {
        mPDInterface.onDateSet(date);
    }
}
```

and when you create the dialog, just add this interface as a parameter, and add what you need to do in the interface.

Option 2:

create a public method in your activity and call it via
(([Your activity name])[your context]).your method;
You're basically casting your context to your activity and using the method
Example:
`((PickDate_main).getContext()).setDateText(date);`